# Client-Server connection response timeout issues

Tags: language-agnostic, timeout, client-server

User creates a `folder` in client and in the client-side code I hit an API to the server to make this persistent for that user. But in some cases, my server is so busy that the request timesout. The server has executed my request but timedout before sending a response back to client. The timeout set is 10 seconds in client. At this point the client thinks that server has not executed its request (of creating a folder) and ends up sending it again. Now I have 2 folders on the server but the user has created only 1 folder in the client. How to prevent this?

One of the ways to solve this is to use a unique ID with each new request. So the ID acts as a distinguisher between old and new requests from client. But this leads to storing these IDs on my server and do a lookup for each API call which I want to avoid.

Other way is to increase the timeout duration. But I dont want to change this from 10 seconds.

Something tells me that there are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of sequence numbering, so that when you resend a request it has the same sequence number as the original request. Then the server can easily discard duplicate requests.

Also you should look into *why* the server responds so slowly. Ten seconds is a **long** time for a computer.

Comment: I was thinking about some kind of hash of the entire request including `GET` params. This way if the hash changes I know its a different request. But this whole approach of sequence-numbering needs me to maintain these hashes in server and do a look-up for every API call. I really want to avoid this. Is there any better thing I can do ?